# Are there any accepted standards for Architectural Diagram component types ? (Stereotypes for Architecture Diagram)

Tags: architecture, components, diagrams

I'm developing the architecture diagram for a system and i need to use generally accepted standards for component types(name of the component and other details) in architecture diagram. (i am currently using "system", "layers", "sub system" and "units" etc). I studied UML notation but there are no architectural diagrams in UML (only deployment diagrams).

So can any one tell me what are the standers of component types (Stereotypes) when developing a architectural diagram?

Thanks

[UML component notation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/dec04/bell/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[4+1 Architectural View Model](http://java.dzone.com/articles/%E2%80%9C41%E2%80%9D-view-model-software) is generally used to document the architecture.

Comment: But Pangea the problem is when we naming the component types we don't have any standard names for them. As a example what is the standard name for the smallest unit of a architect diagram ? is it "unit" or ... ?